# Add records from Details Table after respective Master Table record in Report

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have two tables for Billing, one `Bill_Master` and other is `Bill_Detail`. The records in both tables are as follows...

```
**BILL_MASTER**
id    party    bill_amount
1      abc      500
2      def      600

**BILL_DETAILS**
mstr_id    sr_no    perticular    amount
 1          1        lunch box     100
 1          2        water bag     400
 2          1        pencil boxes  300
 2          2        a4 papers     100
 2          3        staple pins   200
```

Now I want to make a RDLC as per below

```
**RESULT_TABLE**
mstr_id    party      billamount
 1         abc           500
           lunch box     100
           water bag     400
 2         def           600
           pencil boxes  300
           a4 papers     100
           staple pins   200
```

My database is `SQLite`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Do a Sql Join to get the results from the two tables in a `DataSet` .Create a report (EmptyReport) right click report and Edit . Add this section inside `<DataSets>` tag.

```
<DataSet Name="DataSet1">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="mstr_id">
      <DataField>mstr_id</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="party">
      <DataField>party</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="billamount">
      <DataField>billamount</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
```

And then Feed that DataSource to Rdlc Report like this:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ("testReport.rdlc");
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]));
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

On the report after you have done the above. Drag drop the columns in a List. And set GroupBy mstr_id.

Any thing else let me know.